# Should the entity identifier be the email or a non business related numeric id?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm building an application that will be used by some users. Based on the business' logic definition, users will be identified by their email, so no email will be repeated in the whole system. Here es an extract of the UML class diagram:

- [User class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRLBs.png) *(Sorry, I can't embed images due to my low reputation)*

I've been reading how people implement it by using Symfony 4 and the Doctrine ORM, and everybody is letting Doctrine create a numeric ID for being the entity identifier. Based on my diagram, should I do it?

Here is what I have at the moment:

```php
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields="email",
 *     message="error.email_already_registered"
 * )
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Email
     * @Assert\Length(min=4,max=180)
     */
    private $email;
```

Should it be similar to the following code?

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180)
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @Assert\Email
     * @Assert\Length(min=4,max=180)
     */
    private $email;
```

Comment: IMHO you should stick with a numeric ID, this makes it easier if (for example) the email changes.

Comment: I think sticking to convention and reducing the potential issues in the future, keep the use of an ID. It doesn't necessarily have to be exposed. I would also keep what you have done with making the email unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Should it be" depends on your requirements. It is completely fine to use both a unique numeric identifier and setting the e-mail field to be unique (as posted in the first snippet). This helps to build relations between the user entity and other entities, as they have a "simple" field to be used for joining tables then.

If you would use the email address field as the unique identifier for that entity, this value had to be used in all relation tables. I'm not sure whether this would happen automatically, but on changing the address later, you had to propagate this change into all related tables. To avoid trouble, use the numeric identifier - one that should never change and for all time reference that one user entity.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be confuse about UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY.
UNIQUE value can change but PRIMARY KEY should never change BUT both are INDEX

So, for your case, email can change in your business logic or not?

If yes, don't add it as PRIMARY KEY, should be only UNIQUE INDEX. Otherwise, you can use it as PRIMARY KEY.